# Did the Furious 7 team do wrong things in Abu Dhabi?

Tags: fast-and-furious-franchise, furious-7

I saw Sex and the City 2. In that movie, Abu Dhabi was shown in a decent manner, even airport security did not allow sex products in and throughout the movie the decency of the place is maintained.

But in Furious 7, they showed Abu Dhabi as a place where "Bikini Girls enjoy a party outside". Did the Furious 7 team do "bad things" in Abu Dhabi?

Comment: Is it really possible to do the "wrong thing" in Abu Dhabi? That place is a haven of decadence.

Answer (score 5):

Unless the production crew had special permission for things, you have to remember that just because a movie is shown to take place somewhere, **doesn't mean it's actually filmed there.** There's a lot that can be done with special effects to compile different shots together to make them look like the location needed.

Granted this is for television shows, but still, it highlights how shows can be made to look like they're taking place in a specific location, when they were actually filmed on a studio backlot with the locations inserted later by VFX teams.

I can't seem to find it, but in the early days of Hollywood, they actually had a map of locations in and around California that could be used to depict various world locations based on genre type.

Comment: This also helps explain why (many) actors refuse to watch their own movies!

Answer (score 2):

Furious 7 was, in fact, [partially filmed in Abu Dhabi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2820852/locations).  However, I don't think you can say they did "wrong things".  They are trying to represent a foreign, exotic (to Americans) location.  Movies aren't always a perfect representation of real life.  They're supposed to be an *escape* from life.